# Cordova Facebook Connect plugin fail on logout

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am developing a Cordova/Phonegap Android app and  [phonegap-facebook-plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin) version 0.3.2. I was *hardcoding* for a week to get all syncronized. 
Now seems that is working since it logs user correctly but I am having an issue when facebook plugin use Native interface.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', app.utils.RemoteCalls.handleLogin); // Works
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', app.utils.RemoteCalls.handleLogout); // Never fires
```

While FB.getAuthResponse() seems to fire event `'auth.login'` that gets handled by `app.utils.RemoteCalls.handleLogin`, *sometimes* when call FB.logout() it fires a native Alert **Cordova Facebook Connect plugin fail on logout** from facebook-js-sdk.js: line 5120. But it works if I click again on logout launching again FB.logout().

Here is init code:

```
FB.init({
      appId : '***************',
      nativeInterface : CDV.FB,
      status : true,
      cookie : true,
      xfbml : true,
      frictionlessRequests : true,
      useCachedDialogs : true,
      oauth : true
});
```

Another weird thing that surprised me is that `'auth.logout'` never fires. Instead it fires responses like:

```
FB.logout(function(response){
        console.log("[FB.logout] response: " + JSON.stringify(response));
        window.open("index.html");
});
```